# Converting projected coordinates into decimals

Tags: r, coordinates, rgdal

I have the following data set with coordinates in decimals:

```
ID     Longitude  Latitude
 1     -93.2552   58.0879
 1     -93.2558   58.0876
 1     -93.2555   58.0873
```

For a previous project, I projected the coordinates using the following code:

```
  library(rgdal)
  coordinates(data) <- c("longitude", "latitude")
  proj4string(data) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
  data <- spTransform(data, CRS("+init=epsg:5321"))
  data<-as.data.frame(data)
```

Now, I need to re-use the original decimal coordinates. Could anyone tell me how to convert the projected coordinates back into decimal?

Comment: I would suggest creating a new object instead of overwriting the `data` - i.e. `data.transformed <- as.data.frame(spTransform(data, CRS("+init=epsg:5321")))` - this would create a new data frame with the transformed values and preserve the original data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will keep that in mind for my analyses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat your previous steps, but switch the projections in `proj4string` and `spTransform`.

```
library(rgdal)

data_old <- data
coordinates(data_old) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")
proj4string(data_old) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
data_old <- spTransform(data_old, CRS("+init=epsg:5321"))
data_old <- as.data.frame(data_old)

#    ID Longitude Latitude
# 1  1  451077.2  7117021
# 2  1  451037.6  7116991
# 3  1  451051.2  7116956
```

Then, you can just switch the projection in your code to revert back to the original coordinates.

```
data_new <- data_old
coordinates(data_new) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")
proj4string(data_new) <- CRS("+init=epsg:5321")
data_new <- spTransform(data_new, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
data_new <- as.data.frame(data_new)
```

Output

```
  ID Longitude Latitude
1  1  -93.2552  58.0879
2  1  -93.2558  58.0876
3  1  -93.2555  58.0873
```

Another option using `tidyverse` and `sf` could be:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

data_old %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), dim = "XY") %>%
  st_set_crs(5321) %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  extract(geometry,
          c('Longitude', 'Latitude'),
          '\\((.*), (.*)\\)',
          convert = TRUE)
```

Data

```
data <-
  structure(
    list(
      ID = c(1, 1, 1),
      Longitude = c(-93.2552,-93.2558,-93.2555),
      Latitude = c(58.0879, 58.0876, 58.0873)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-3L)
  )
```